# How to use eval in karate for if and else case?

Tags: karate

need a small help related to this only right now i have an api which return data `price": { "pretax_price": 7002.84, "rack_rate": 8140.82, "wallet_deductable_amount": 0, "voucher_amount": 0, "total_discount_percent": 92.75, "net_payable_amount": 4131.68, }`.Now what i am trying to do is `* def pretax =price.pretax_price` should be called only if `* def valueFromDB == true` where valueFromDB is coming from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please. Read. The. Docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

```
* def pretax = valueFromDB ? price.pretax_price : pretax
```